# Correctly handling undo/redo with nested method calls in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos, undo, nsundomanager

I couldn't think of a better way to ask this question, so I apologize if the title makes no sense. Basically, I'm implementing Undo/Redo at the controller-level for a portion of my app, and I keep coming across this niggling issue. I have two methods:

```
- (void)addNote:(BSDNote *)note;
- (void)duplicateNote:(BSDNote *)note;
```

In the `-addNote:` method, a `note` object is added to a mutable array. I also update some other stuff, but for the purpose of my example, let's just say an object is added to an array. Before adding the object to the array however, I register an Undo operation with the document's `NSUndoManager`, like so:

```
if ( [self.undoManager levelsOfUndo] > 0 ) {
    [self.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
    [self.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
}

[self.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(deleteNote:) object:note];
[self.undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"Add Note", @"Add Note undo action name")];
```

By itself, it makes sense, and everything's all good. The thing I'm unsure of is when calling the `-addNote:` method from within my `-duplicateNote:` method.

In the `-duplicateNote:` method, the `note` object is copied, then added to the mutable array using the `-addNote:` method. Since I'm duplicating the object, I want to add an undo operation to the stack for `-duplicateNote:`, not `-addNote:`.

The only thing I can think of is to do something like this from within the `-duplicateNote:` method:

```
[self.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(deleteNote:) object:note];
[self.undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"Duplicate Note", @"Duplicate Note undo action name")];

// I make a copy of the note here (noteCopy), along with other miscellaneous stuff.

[self.undoManager disableUndoRegistration];
[self addNote:noteCopy];
[self.undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
```

Am I crazy in thinking this is an okay way to handle this situation? The entire "grouping" of undo/redo operations kind of makes my head hurt, so I'm sure I'm overlooking something, or there is a Better Way®. If someone knows of this better way, would you mind explaining it to me (like I'm five)?

Comment: You should probably look into the Memento pattern: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Comment: I think in that pattern its recommended that every action is singular and opaque. I think you should only record the call to 'duplicate', never to 'add' since its called internally. You might have to restructure your code to achieve this effect in a clean way.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs Thanks for the knowledge! I've never heard of this pattern, so this will be an interesting read. I'm already *kind of* doing this because I read somewhere in the documentation about having "primitive" methods which do the internal work (aka `set<#Property#>` on the model), while the displayed action name would be the "higher-level" action, like Duplicate or Copy. I guess I'm just torn between the different levels of granularity. For instance, if I had a graphic that was resizable, I wouldn't want an undo for every single pixel value change, I'd only want one: "Undo Resize" or

Answer (score 0):

Ben, I think you're overthinking it. If the last instance created is a "duplicate note", then it would make sense to add an "undo" to the stack when the duplicateNote method executes.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted you, considering I need all the help I can get. Let me even your score back out! Anyway, you're probably right in regard to the "overthinking" aspect of this because I tend to do that. The only thing though is that if I were to add "Duplicate Note" to the undo stack, wouldn't it be messed up? If I undo the "Duplicate Note" action, it would then say, "Undo Add Note," right? I think I'm confusing myself as I type this. This whole thing is turning into UNDOCEPTION.

Comment: It should not happen if `duplicateNote` is an opaque method (i.e.: internals aren't visible, so caller would have no idea that duplicate uses `addNote` internally).